# No Module Named Tensorflow - Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm pretty new to Tensorflow. I've installed the package using

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

When I import tensorflow now, I get the No Module named Tensorflow error. I've been searching for a way out and have failed. It wold mean a lot if someone could help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are working on a virtual environment..?
So...you installed tensorflow on your computer but the environment is isolated

Comment: Yeah...that;s what happened. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

run following commands:

```
conda create -n tensorflow
activate tensorflow
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

else you can install it with pip command:

```
pip install tensorflow
```